# TFS Get Latest Version ignoring files

Tags: tfs

I have the following scenario in my TFS project:

```
- /RootFolder
-- /Project1
---- /Web
------ /FrontEnd
-------- /Images
-------- /Catalogs
-------- /Css
-------- /Js
-------- /Folder1
-------- /Folder2
-------- /Folder3
-------- /Folder4
-------- ..Lots of html files
------ /Code
-------- /Module1
-------- /Module2
-------- /Module3
```

I need to refresh my local code with the code from TFS and I'd like to select the "Project1" folder and get the latest version recursively from there. However the folders Images contains lots of images, and the folder catalogs contains lots of pdf files (about 4gb, in 700 pdf files).

I could go folder by folder, selecting get latest version, but it would be very time consuming. I can't get the latest version from the "root folder" because it takes very, very, very long.

My doubts are:

1. How and where can I specify to tfs to "ignore" the get latest version from certain folders? Or specific files or extensions?
2. Any suggestions, besides changing the whole structure? (unfortunatelly I can't do that)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to script something or create a batch file using tf.exe

[tf.exe Get command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx)

```
tf get [itemspec] [/version:versionspec] [/all] [/overwrite] [/force [/remap] [/recursive] [/preview] [/noautoresolve] [/noprompt] [/login:username,[password]]
```

eg. Get all the .cs files:

```
tf get *.cs /recursive
```

or get latest in Project1/Web

```
tf.exe get /recursive $/Project1/Web
```

You could also mess with your workspace mappings to cloak the folders with huge items or explicitly map certain folders but that might be more time consuming.